# Hexedit / Ghidra Byte Viewer wont allow deletion of bytes

Tags: ghidra, hex

I was playing around with some golang code I wrote, and I modified the Go BuildID. However, I had to pad whatever I wanted the buildID to be with characters so that it was the length of the original string.

I found that both `hexedit` and Ghirda's Byte Viewer (which allows modifying bytes) do not allow you to delete bytes (unless I cannot figure out how) from a file. I am wondering whats the reasoning, is there some sort of checksum they don't want you to overwrite? What about files where a checksum is not a concern?

Which tool can I use to modify hex bytes, including deleting them from the file?

Comment: Deleting bytes means changing the file-size and all sections after the delete position move "forward" the number of deleted bytes. This means you would have to update all pointers and other references. So if you miss just one pointer/reference then the executable will be defect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting bytes would move around anything after the edit, breaking pointers which would break the whole binary, so Ghidra doesn't even allow you to do it.